# How to lookup values and insert contents between two spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, vba, search, lookup

I have to manage a lot of information in Excel. I have two spreadsheets in one workbook. The first one shows different names on the second row (Abasolo TAMPS 1, Abasolo TAMPS 10, etc) and the second one shows also names (Column A) but next to them there are also some parameters like Wind Speed, Distance, X and Y (Column B). Does any one know how to programm in VBA a way to tell Excel to take the first value on the column A (Say Abasolo, TAMPS 17) on the second spreadsheet (image of the right), look them up in the second row of the first spreadsheet (image on the left), take the set of parameters next to the name and insert them on row 11 and the intersecting column on the first spreadsheet (image of the left, where the "2's" are). That for all the values on column A of the second spreadsheet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `VLOOKUP` to achieve this.

Sheet 2 parameters
[image: Sheet2]

Sheet 1 VLookup
[image]

I used the function

```
=VLOOKUP(B$4,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE)
```

in Cell B6 on sheet1.

To maintain line breaks, you will need to ensure wrap text is used for the destination cells as shown below

[image: Wrap Text]

---

You can read more about `VLOOKUP` here.

[VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

Comment: It does maintain line breaks, you just have to apply "Wrap Text" to the destination cells.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say it doesn't do anything to line breaks, or anything else, it returns the value of the cell.

Comment: Very good. I just checked, and this is correct. I'll add it to the answer for the sake of completeness. Thank you @BenjaminWarren

Comment: yeah that has to do it, but strangely I get only #REF values in the cells, any ideas why?

Comment: You're using a cell reference that isn't valid somewhere in the function. see http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/correct-a-ref-error-HP005203948.aspx